# Allow visiting website B only if you visited website A first

Tags: cookies

Having two websites: `A` and `B`. I want that the users that open website `B` to get redirected to another website (e.g. `http://example.com`) if they *didn't* visit the website `A`.

To do this I tried to set a cookie on website `B` (by just loading a page on website `A`, setting the cookie). When opening the website `B` I check for that cookie.

This works nice, except on Safari. Safari blocks setting the cookie on website `B`. I searched a lot and found out that Safari blocks the third-party cookies by default.

Another solution to the problem could be using the `Referer` header (when clicking a link on website `A` the referer will be sent to website `B`)–this fails for the users that don't want to get tracked and they disabled the referer header.

Is there a simple solution to this problem, without having a database where we store the ips or something similar?

I feel like this is a classical problem that should have a classical solution, but I couldn't find any.

The question is: how can I know if the user that opens website B navigated first to website A?

The navigation from website A to B can be done using a link/button.

Comment: Is this a *security* mechanism or a *convenience* for the user? If it's security, you won't want to use anything that can be spoofed by the client, such as referrer.

Comment: @TTT It would be just a coding question if Safary didn't exist at all. :) From what I understood for security reasons, Safari blocks the cross-origin cookies, by default. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35174003/1420197) is the similar question I posted (it contains code). I was just wondering if this is a known problem with a known solution. :)

Comment: By my question I meant, are you doing the redirect for security reasons or just for a convenience to the user? And btw, other browsers can be configured to block 3rd party cookies too...

Comment: @TTT That's a feature my client wants to have: the user should be able to visit website B only after visiting website A. I guess the final fix is to make a POST request with some data in it from website A to website B. That would create cookies in the response and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some authentication scheme, where clicking that button will make server generate the token that is signed or maced and make the second server trust that. Then you can pass that as a parameter in the URL, but this scheme will allow anyone who gets the token to use that (I am not sure if you are doing that for security or as a some UI feature).

Another simple solution if your users are authenticated is just add a database entry after the first logon to the site A and then read it on the second site.

Comment: That's the thing: I want to keep this very lightweight, so having a database wouldn't be something I want. Any ideas how to generate that token? The token should be valid only for one the user... somehow. I also thought that maybe using a POST request instead of GET could be a solution. What do you think?

Comment: You can use some JWT standards for token, or use your own, you just need to include the userid in that token. It won't be possible to forge, but anyone who has that token can reuse it later. You can look into OAuth protocol and kind of abuse it to get what you want I suppose, but it can be quite an overkill. Regarding the JWT there are multiple libraries in most languages to generate it it (see jwt.io). You can also pass it in a post which can be better since there won't be any publicly visible URL.

Comment: I like Ilya's approach.  To make the token so that it can only be used once, just encode a timestamp in it, and do a check on server B that the timestamp was less than X seconds ago.  If you're concerned about users being able to reverse-engineer it, just encrypt the token.